Sample uniformly on ellipsoid by transforming samples on sphere
Problem Statement
Suppose $\pi(x) = \mathcal{N}(0_d, \Sigma)$ is a multivariate normal distribution centered at the origin with covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Given a suitable value $c > 0$, I want to obtain uniformly-distributed points on the $c$-level set of $\pi$.
My Own Attempt
The level-set is an ellipsoid, since
$$
\log\pi^{-1}(\{\log c\}) = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d\,:\, -\frac{d}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\log\det\Sigma - \frac{1}{2}x^\top\Sigma^{-1} x = \log c\right\}
$$
can be written as
$$
x^\top A x = 1
$$
where
$$
A = \frac{1}{b}\Sigma^{-1}, \qquad \qquad b = -2\log c - d\log(2\pi) - \log\det\Sigma
$$
According to Wikipedia, if one can find a positive square root $A^{1/2}$ such that $A = A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$
then it is enough to sample points $Y^{(i)} \sim \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ uniformly on the sphere
and then set
$$
Z^{(i)} = A^{1/2} Y^{(i)}
$$
I tried this, with the following algorithm:

Sample $X^{(i)}\sim\mathcal{N}(0_d, I_d)$
Normalize $Y^{(i)}) = X^{(i)} / \|X^{(i)}\|$)
Set $Z^{(i)} = L Y^{(i)}$, where $L$ is the cholesky decomposition of $A = (b\Sigma)^{-1}$
but this does not work.

Simple Coding Check
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn
# Define the multivariate normal
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1234)
Sigma = np.array([[1.0, 0.3], [0.3, 0.5]])
pi = mvn(mean=np.zeros(2), cov=Sigma)
c = 0.05
b = -2*np.log(c) - 2*np.log(2*np.pi) - np.log(np.linalg.det(Sigma))
# Sample from unit sphere
x = rng.normal(size=2)
x_sphere = x / np.linalg.norm(x)
# Transform sample
A = np.linalg.inv(b*Sigma)
L = np.linalg.cholesky(A)
x_transformed = L.dot(x_sphere)
# Check if it is on the correct level set
print("Level set value: ", c, " but point on: ", mvn.pdf(x_transformed))


Note: the method works in that it does produce samples from some ellipsoid with the correct "covariance structure", but it does not work in that it does not give samples on the $c$-level set
